# VS Code suggestions for HTML attributes and JavaScript properties not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, ide

I've just started the second part of a two-part online programming course through uni. In the first part, we learned Java and used IntelliJ as the IDE. The second part is web development, and we are supposed to use VS Code.

I've noticed that VS Code didn't seem to be nearly as "smart" with code suggestions for JavaScript and HTML as IntelliJ was with Java. To compare "like for like" I tried typing the same code into IntelliJ to see whether it also provided better suggestions for Javascript and HTML too. It definitely does and without any config or downloading extensions.

So I tried various extensions for VS Code with no luck. I've included a couple of comparisons as links.

Does anyone know how to improve VS Code's suggestions in the below cases?

To be clear, VS Code does give suggestions other than abc.

So far I have tried a clean install, and a number of popular extensions but no luck so far.

Appreciate any help :)

[Examples of code suggestions VS Code v IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxDkz.png)

[VS Code suggestions are enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBBUW.png)

Comment: You may just install VSCode Extension snippet for Javascript

Comment: you tried https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense ? see as well https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: I have tried extensions for HTML and Javascript, as well as the Intellicode extension. None of these worked for me.  Do you have a specific example of an extension that works for you in either/both of the two examples provided in the screenshot linked in the original post?